# Newby question: caching, is Page module enough, and can Stash cach template without setting up htaccess file?

Tags: stash, pages, speed

I am working on a site that has potential to attract a lot of traffic, says my client. I am reading here and there how to build efficient, for speed. One of the things I am looking at is the use of Stash for caching pages with static content. (I did use Stash for something else in another project)

My questions.
1) Is the pages module enough for this?
2) Is a htaccess file needed for page caching with Stash? The documentation makes me a bit unsure.

Thanks.

Comment: The Pages module has nothing whatsoever to do with caching or speed. I think you may need to re-read the documentation. All the Pages module does is create an association between a single entry and a template using a given URI.

Comment: Thank you. I agree I must study some more. The problem with most documentations is that they are written as a guideline for the user to describe what one can do with it. My problem is that I want to know how it works and why things happen a certain way. For me it is the only way to make choices and decisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mod_rewrite rules for caching are only needed if you're using the static cache method.

Static caching works by writing the HTML output of an EE template to a static file; when the browser requests a URL, mod_rewrite in .htaccess will check to see if that static file exists, if it does, it will serve the HTML from the static file, and, EE won't even be aware the request took place.

If the static HTML file doesn't exist, EE will handle the request as usual (with the Pages module), and, if static caching is enabled for the page, write the output of the page load to the static cache, so the next user who requests that page will get content from the file, instead of from EE, if that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you. If I would like to keep things simple, for starters, is there much difference in speed between the two methodes? Pages module and Stash addon? The pages I would like to serve as static has no dynamic parts in them, content gets seldom updated.

Comment: Your answer, and the comment above, did help me a lot tu understand a bit more. Thank you both!